# Example socket app doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets

I'm studying `java.net` and trying to make a simple app. here is the code:

**EDIT:** My fault, sorry, but the main problem still exists. Here is corrected code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        try{

            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3128);
            args[0] = args[0]+"\n"+s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
                    +":"+s.getLocalPort();
            s.getOutputStream().write(args[0].getBytes());

            byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
            int r = s.getInputStream().read(buf);
            String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

            System.out.println(data);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("init error: "+e);
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to start it it gives me the following error:

```
init error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

what is the possible reason of this?

**UPD:** here is the rest trace:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/mikhail/Загрузки/idea-IU-123.155/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/producer/target/classes:/home/mikhail/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/commons-lang-2.3.jar:/home/mikhail/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.0/pdfbox-1.8.0.jar:/home/mikhail/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/1.8.0/fontbox-1.8.0.jar:/home/mikhail/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/mikhail/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/jempbox/1.8.0/jempbox-1.8.0.jar:/home/mikhail/Загрузки/idea-IU-123.155/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.messagedna.dlp.main.Main
```

Comment: How was the program invoked? Any command-line arguments supplied?

Comment: @hmjd no any. just started from the ide

Comment: You should post the whole stack trace and not only the exception message. Also catching `Exception` is not recommended.

Comment: Well if you're not passing arguments then `args[0]` is out of bounds. You can pass arguments from the IDE too. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Even if you are passing an argument, you will get the next exception (`NullPointerException`) since you have not configured your Socket (it has no address). You should probably go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: @Andreas I was told that it will send to the standard address or so

Comment: @NikitinMikhail you were told wrong. Read [apidoc for that constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket())

Comment: No, there is no standard server address - you need to connect the socket, at least, like `s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("myserver", 80));`

Comment: @Andreas, Yes, you are right, I've corrected this but I still have the  same error

Comment: @NikitinMikhail Your corrected code works for me (provided that I pass something as command line parameter). I used a server where an http server is running at port 80, and I get back some html code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the possible reason of this?

The reason for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is that you have not passed any arguments to your program. Hence, `args[0]` does not refer to a valid array index (btw: I would create a separate local variable instead of assigning to the `args[]` array. Technically it is possible, but I would not consider this "good style").

When you pass a parameter to your program, you will get a `NullPointerException` since you have not configured your Socket. You need, at least, connect it to some server, e.g. like this:

```
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("myserver.example.com", 1234));
```

Then, when there is an appropriate server running at port 1234 at "myserver.example.com", you will be able to send and receive some data.

For more information about network programming in Java, you should go through the [Sockets tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).